# c# control name

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I would like ask about the name of the control that is used in MS Project for scheduling? and if it is possible to give me some idea how programmatically it works?

Comment: Microsoft Project was not written in WPF.

Comment: Would you be able to clarify your question? Perhaps include a screenshot, or describe what you would ultimately like to do? It will help the community to be able to provide helpful answers.

Comment: what has WPF got to do with C#. C# doesn't imply WPF!

Comment: @Andy: The question was misleadingly tagged with 'wpf'

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the [Gantt Chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart) is a .NET control - MS Project is a C/C++ application and this is probably custom written.

As such, you will not be able to use that specific one. There are many third party .NET Gantt Chart controls.

Answer (score 0):

User interfaces of the sophistication of MS Project are never programmed with a single control and as Oded already pointed out, it's likely to be a custom C++ API used.

There is a lot of information on Project in MSDN, for example the [2007 Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb244274(v=office.12).aspx).

It is possible, depending on your actual needs, that you could embed a COM object to invoke Project. Sorry, I don't know exactly how to do that but if you research the topic, please add your results to the question :-)

As a matter of interest, Expression Blend is the first major application developed by Microsoft that was developed in a programming framework that they were releasing to third party developers. (Excluding the bottom-level Win32 API). In particular, it's the first time such a big application has been developed concurrently with the framework and the team able to feed their experiences back to the framework team. WPF's inherent patterns were significantly improved as a result.